# Python Attribute Error with multiple classes and Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, attributes, tkinter, syntax-error

I'm trying create a gui using Tkinter that grabs a username and password and connects to a remote server and does a function. I slapped together some messy code and it more or less worked, but when I tried to recreate it in a  tidy module, it broke. Its probably a newbie python error, but I can't spot it. EDIT: to clarify, when it worked, the only class was setupGui and any methods were under that class. Now that I've separated the gui from the methods, its not working.

```
class setupGui(object):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      ##omited general frame stuff 

       self.userIn = ttk.Entry(self.topFrame, width = 20)
       self.userIn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
       self.passIn = ttk.Entry(self.topFrame, width = 20, show ="*")
       self.passIn.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

       #Buttons
       self.setupbtn = ttk.Button(self.topFrame, text = "Start Setup", command = setup().startSetup())
       self.setupbtn.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 10)

class setup(object):
   def__init__(self):
      self.userName = setupGui.userIn.get()
      self.userPass = setupGui.passIn.get()
   def startSetup(self):
      self.another_related_fucntion # about 4 related functions actually

if __name__ == '__main__':
root = Tk()
gui = setupGui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And if I don't have the command attached to the button, everything works fine (but obviously does diddly squat except look pretty). And when I attached the command, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "macSetup.py", line 211, in <module>
 gui = setupGui(root)
 File "macSetup.py", line 45, in __init__
self.setupbtn = ttk.Button(self.topFrame, text = "Start Setup", command = setup().startSetup())
File "macSetup.py", line 69, in __init__
self.userName = setupGui.userIn.get()
AttributeError: type object 'setupGui' has no attribute 'userIn'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `userIn` is set up as an instance variable of `setupGui` objects, not as an attribute of the `setupGui` class itself.

The simplest solution would be to merge the `setupGui` and `setup` classes to move `startSetup` in as a method of `setupGui`, then use `command=self.startSetup` when you initialize `setupbtn`—this calls `startSetup` as a bound method, and `self` should thus refer to the `setupGui` object, which you can then use e.g. `self.userIn.get()` and `self.passIn.get()` on.

If you'd rather keep the logic you have in the `setup` class out of the `setupGui` class, you can separate it out like this:

```
class setup(object):
    def __init__(self, username, userpass):
        self.userName = username
        self.userPass = userpass

    def startSetup(self):
        # as before
```

then add this method to the `setupGui` class:

```
def dosetup(self):
    setup(self.userIn.get(), self.passIn.get()).startSetup()
```

and instantiate the `Button` with `command=self.dosetup`.  (I would personally make the `setup` class a standalone function, but I don't know how complicated your `startSetup` routine actually is, so I assume you have a good reason for making it a class.)

Comment: Thats how I had it set up originally. I generally don't like having functions mixed in with guis. In Java, I'd have them all in separate packages even. 

I tried changing  self.userName = setupGui.userIn.get() to self.userName = setupGui(root).userIn.get(), but I got a crazy recursion error.  I also tried gui instead of root (since its defined in the __main__), but it says its undefined. 

Which is the more pythonic route to take?

Comment: See edit.  I think this will work for you.  (Actually, see the most recent edit, because I messed up `dosetup` the first time.)

Answer (score 1):

The `command` attribute takes a reference to a function, but you're calling the function and giving the result to the `command` attribute. The net result is that you're calling the setup function at the time that you create the button, not at the time that you click the button. Things aren't fully initialized yet, so you get the error.

You're doing this:

```
self.setupbtn = ttk.Button(self.topFrame, text = "Start Setup", command = setup().startSetup())
```

... when you should be doing something like this:

```
self.setupbtn = ttk.Button(self.topFrame, text = "Start Setup", command = setup().startSetup)
```

Note the lack of the trailing `()` on `startSetup`.

If you don't want to instantiate `setup` until the button is clicked, you have a couple of choices. The best, arguably, is to create a method:

```
def _launch_setup(self):
    setup().setupGui()
...
self.setupbtn = ttk.Button(..., command=self._launch_setup)
```

You could also use a lambda, but in this case I recommend a named method.

Answer (score 0):

The class `setupGui` itself doesn't have the attribute `userIn`.

In the `__init__` method of `setupGui` you give the attribute to the *instance*, not the class.